# Unable to resolve getApplicationContext and startActivity methods in shake event listener: Android Studio

Tags: android, accelerometer, shake, launching-application

I am trying to implement a shake event listener and below is my code. It is Android Studio environment if it matters. It just says cannot resolve method getApplicationContext or even startActivity. Can anyone help me find my mistake?

```
package com.shaivaldesai.shake;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;

/**
 * Created by Shaival Desai on 7/3/14.
 */
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    // Low pass filter
    private float calcMaxAcceleration(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        final float alpha = 0.8f;

        float[] gravity = {-9.81f};

        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * sensorEvent.values[2];

        float accX = sensorEvent.values[0] - gravity[0];
        float accY = sensorEvent.values[1] - gravity[1];
        float accZ = sensorEvent.values[2] - gravity[2];

        float max1 = Math.max(accX, accY);
        return Math.max(max1, accZ);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //handleShake(sensorEvent);}
    float maxAcc = calcMaxAcceleration(sensorEvent);
       // void handleShake(sensorEvent){
        //float maxAcc = calcMaxAcceleration(sensorEvent);
        if(maxAcc>=15) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do that if I knew what is it and how I could do that! I am very new to this. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods don't exist in `SensorEventListener`. You must have copied this from a class that extends `Activity`. You'll need to call these methods on a `Context` object. You should define a custom constructor on your `ShakeEventListener` that takes a `Context` object:

```
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {
    private Context mContext;

    public ShakeEventListener(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** omitting unchanged methods **/

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //handleShake(sensorEvent);}
        float maxAcc = calcMaxAcceleration(sensorEvent);
        // void handleShake(sensorEvent){
        //float maxAcc = calcMaxAcceleration(sensorEvent);
        if(maxAcc>=15) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to guide me to some good example of custom constructor?

Comment: That worked. . Do I have to mention the ShakeEventListener in Manifest? How do I do that?

Comment: It's not a Service, Activity, Receiver or Provider, so it doesn't have to be in the manifest.

Comment: right, I am curious about what triggers the listener. . Neither my Main activity, Nor my Boot Receiver is saying anything about starting the Listener as of now.